# Compute differences of pair elements in array of pairs compile time

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, stdarray

In the code below, I aim to construct an array of `N` elements that contains the differences between two `std::pair` elements compile time. Is there a way to achieve this using templates, as it has to work for arbitrary size `N`?

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<int N>
std::array<int, N> make_array(
        const std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N>& ranges)
{
    // Need to construct array compile time with difference between pair elements.
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 2> a = make_array<2>({{ {1,3}, {2,9} }}); // a = {2, 7}
    std::array<int, 1> b = make_array<1>({{ {5,6} }}); // b = {1}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over the array?

Comment: @PasserBy. How can I construct a fixed-size `std::array` compile-time in a loop?

Comment: `std::array<int, N> arr; for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = ranges[i].second - ranges[i].first; return arr;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the loop:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> make_array(
        const std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N>& ranges)
{
    std::array<int, N> res{};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        res[i] = ranges[i].second - ranges[i].first;
    }
    return res;
}
```

It might be `constexpr` since C++17.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b8fb4f2ac42510b)

Comment: I completely overlooked the loop being `constexpr`. Elegant and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++14 (so `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`) it's easy

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<int, N>  makeArrayHelper
    (std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> const & r,
     std::index_sequence<Is...> const)
 { return {{ r[Is].second - r[Is].first ... }}; }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto makeArray (std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> const & r)
 { return makeArrayHelper(r, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr std::array<int, 2> a
      = makeArray<2>({{ {1,3}, {2,9} }}); // a = {2, 7}

   constexpr std::array<int, 1> b
      = makeArray<1>({{ {5,6} }}); // b = {1}

   static_assert( a[0] == 2, "!" );
   static_assert( a[1] == 7, "!" );
   static_assert( b[0] == 1, "!" );
 }
```

P.s.: I've renamed `makeArray()` the function to reduce the risk of name collision with the `make_array()` in `std::experimental`